# How to round two decimals

Tags: c#

I want to take the following string "4.29 x 4.30 x 2.58mm" and round the two decimals on each of these numbers in C#. Any ideas?

```
4.29 x 4.30 x 2.58mm
4.29 = 4.30
4.30 = 4.30
2.58 = 2.60
```

The result string should be 4.30 x 4.30 x 2.60

Comment: You would need to first obtain the numbers, round them, and then convert it back into a string.

Comment: I would solve if by using a `Regex.Replace` to extract the numeric parts, convert each match by `Convert.ToDouble()` -> `Math.Round()` -> `ToString()`.

Comment: Given you haven't explained what kind of rounding you want, please ensure your extra sample inputs include the following values - 4.25, 4.35, 4, 4.05.

Comment: You can try regular expressions:   for given `string source = "4.29 x 4.30 x 2.58mm";` you can replace numbers as `var result = Regex.Replace(source, @"[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?", m => double.TryParse(m.Value, out var d) ? Math.Round(d, 1).ToString("F2") : m.Value);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have your string:

```
string str = "4.29 x 4.30 x 2.58mm";
```

Maybe remove the `mm`

```
str = str.Replace("mm", "");
```

Split them:

```
string[] nums = str.Split(new[] { " x " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Round them:

> `Math.Round(Double, Int32)`
>
> Rounds a double-precision floating-point value to a specified number of fractional digits, and rounds midpoint values to the nearest even number.

```
foreach(string n in nums)
{
    n = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(n), 1).ToString();
}
```

Comment: This likely won't work in an environment, where the current culture does not use the dot as a decimal separator (try "de-DE" for example, that one uses a comma). So if the input string _always_ uses a dot, you might want to specify using the invariant culture for example when converting to double. Or in this case to decimal, as that seems to be more appropriate here.

Comment: This rounds to the nearest integer (So the input `"4.29"` rounds to `4` and not `4.3` as OP requested). If you change it to `Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(n), 1)` it should work (the overload lets you specify how many fractional digits you want).